# Webscraping search parameter confusion

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

[image]

I am having problems extracting this price from the html code.
I know normally the code would be something like:
productlist = soup.find('div', class_='insert class string')
How would you recommend setting up python code to extract that? I am still new to using python and webscraping. Thank you for your time and advice.

Comment: `print(soup.find("div", {"data-test": "product-price"}).getText())`

Answer (score 0):

You can scrape it using the html class:

```
productlist = soup.find(class_ = 'style_PriceFontSize-sc-17wlxvr-0 ceEMdT').get_text()
```

or:

```
productlust =  soup.find("div", {"data-test": "product-price"}).get_text()
```

Comment: thank you for the response! When I use those I get an exception thrown that says 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_text'. If I take off the 'get_text', the program returns none.

Comment: Can you upload the full page?

Comment: https://www.target.com/p/hanes-men-s-big-tall-ecosmart-fleece-crew-neck-sweatshirt/-/A-79691587?preselect=54234439#lnk=sametab

Comment: Its not the exact same page but it has the exact same structure. I am trying to learn how to search webpages with more complicated structures. If you have any recommendations on websites other than the beautifulsoup documentation (I am pretty sure I looked at everything on there), then please let me know.